# Akka MapReduce configuration with ZeroMQ?

Tags: mapreduce, akka, zeromq, akka-zeromq

I'm new to Akka and would like to build a small framework that allows multiple distributed patterns e.g. MapReduce, Publish-Subscribe, etc. I have seen that it is possible using ZeroMQ as the networking provider for Akka and I actually prefer it.

However, when I see some of the [MapReduce examples](https://github.com/write2munish/Akka-Essentials/tree/master/WordCountMapReduce) they all rely on the netty.io framework for networking. In order to have a single networking provider ZeroMQ ... is there a simple way to replace the netty io networking with ZeroMQ in MapReduce example configurations such as this one [application.conf](https://github.com/write2munish/Akka-Essentials/blob/master/WordCountMapReduce/src/resource/application.conf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ømq-based Akka remote transport has not yet been written as far as I know, so the answer to the question as I understand it would be “no” (but I’m not entirely sure that I understand what you want to achieve).

Comment: the question is how to replace netty.io with zeromq in that example so I would only depend on zeromq and not on two networking provider frameworks.

Comment: You write your own RemoteTransport using 0Mq and then you configure Akka to use that